# Retrieving data from multiple tables through Get() method in web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have just started with web API and got my first Get method successfully implemented. I was able to retrieve the data and show it to the client. Now I have to retrieve data from two tables through a single Get method which I am not able too. Here's my code for retrieving data from a single table.

```
public HttpResponsemessage Get(string Login, string Password)
{
  using (Accord_BMHEntities entities = new Accord_BMHEntities())
  {
    Login = Login.Trim();
    EncryptDecrypt EncryptDecryptObj = new EncryptDecrypt();

    string EncryptedPassword = 
            EncryptDeccrypt.Encrypt(Login.Trim().ToUpper(), Password);

    var userLogin = entities.ITPLUsers.firstOrDefault(e => e.Login == Login  
                & e.Password ==  EncryptedPassword        

   if (UserLogin == null)
   {
     return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
   }
   else
   {
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK , UserLogin)
   }
  }
 }
```

EmpMaster.cs

```
public partial class EmpMaster
{
  [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", n 
  CA2212:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]

  Public EmpMaster()
  {
    this.EmpPersonal = new HashSet<EmpPersonal>();
  }

  Public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
  Public int DivisionId { get; set; }
  Public int ResumeId { get; set; }
  Public int GroupId { get; set; }
  Public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
  Public int WorkplaceId { get; set; }
  Public int DesignationId { get; set; }
  Public int Code { get; set; }
  Public int DesignationId { get; set; }

  [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", n 
  CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

  public virtual ICOllection<EmpPersonal> EmpPersonals { get; set; }
}
```

EmpPersonal.cs

```
Public partial class EmpPersonal
{
  Public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
  Public int DivisionID { get; set; }
  Public short Gender { get; set; }
  Public short BloodGroup { get; set; }
  Public string FlatNo { get; set; }
  Public string Premises { get; set; }
  Public string Street { get; set; }
  Public string Area { get; set; }
  Public string City { get; set; }
  Public string StateId { get; set; }
  Public string CountryId { get; set; }

  Public virtual EmpMaster EmpMaster { get; set; }
 }
```

Please note : there are many more properties in both the class. Just to save time i have mentioned some of it.

Comment: Why can't you have 2 methods and call them both on the client?  It's also pretty unclear what you're asking here and where the problem is

Comment: you got data from ITPLUsers, what is the second table that you want to retrieve data?

Comment: @p3tch: I'll be creating a different controller as it will be a different client request. In that i'll be fetching the data through get method. But the data that i'll be fetching are in two different tables. previously i fetched the data from a single table as mentioned in the above code.

Comment: @DanNguyen: Second table is EmpPersonal

Comment: How are you going to use the second table and what result you expect?

Comment: You need to show Accord_BMHEntities class. EmpPersonal is an entity like ITPLUser, so you can query EmpPersonal same as you did with ITPLUser, I mean utilizing LINQ to Entity. Then in the action method, you have 2 data for EmpPersonal and ITPLUser, then you return an instance of a class that wrap two data above. If you want to more details, you must provide more about Accord_BMHEntities and which EmpPersonal objects you want to return

Comment: @JianpingLiu: That's exactly what i am looking for. How am i suppose to use my second table to retrieve my complete data? I am expecting all the information related to a particular employee.

Comment: @DanNguyen: Ok Dan. Thank you. Also Dan, what if i want to retrieve data from two different databases in a single get method?

Comment: If you have two, so in the action method you have not just Accord_BMHEntities but also someotherEntities class. Accord_BMHEntities is used to query data from the first database, someotherEntities is used to query the second database

Comment: @DanNguyen: Thank you so much Dan.

Comment: Please add the class definition code for the EmpMaster and EmpPersonal

Comment: @lonut : I have added the mentioned class.

Comment: Seeing and somewhat understanding the error that i am getting i think its getting into an infinite loop because both the entity is calling the another and its never ending. Please someone? i need to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have modeled the relation between the entities, you could use the Entity Framweork Include method (for eager loading) or Load method (for lazy loading).

Docs here: [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Otherwise you could return an anonymous type:

```
var userLogin = entities.ITPLUsers.firstOrDefault(e => e.Login == Login  
            & e.Password ==  EncryptedPassword;
var empPersonal = entities.EmpPersonal.Where(....your condition...);
if (UserLogin == null)
{
   return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
}
else
{
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,new {userlogin = UserLogin, empPersonal = empPersonal});
}
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that my tables EmpMaster and EmpPersonal has Primary key and foreign key relation due to which i am getting an error "System.InvalidOperationException" when i run the above code. please help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want user address from Address entity along with user data. You have 2 options here. You can either use linq and join to get all related data with one query or you can get user and address datas one by one. In the end, you need to consolidate the data and return one result set since you want to return all of them in a single response.

You obviously need a resultModel for your endpoint.
Like;

```
public class UserResultModel
{
    //Properties from User entity
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    //Properties from Address entity
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

You need to fill this resultModel and return it.

Irrelevant suggestion: I suggest not to check user's authentication like that. MVC has a really nice feature called Filters(Authorization Filters for more detailed)

Answer (score -1):

Try Linq with joins by matching keys. You will get an example from msdn site.[Msdn site](http://https:learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/cshrap/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)